# tornado python gives attribute error 'none type object has no attribute'

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, websocket, tornado

```
#!/usr/bin/python27
import tornado  
import tornado.websocket
import tornado.wsgi
import motor
import json
import jsonpickle
import uuid
from py2neo import neo4j, cypher
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        db = self.settings['db'] 
Class ChatWebSocket(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    ids={}
    frd={}
    def my_callback(result, error):
        print 'result', repr(result)
        IOLoop.instance().stop()
    def on_message(self, message):
        def get_current_user(self):
           print(self)
        to=db.today
       data=json.loads(message)
       print(data)
       s=str(data['who'])            
       if (data['st']=='me'):



        if ''+s+'' in ChatWebSocket.ids:
            del ChatWebSocket.ids[''+s+'']
            ChatWebSocket.ids[''+s+'']=self
            print("sf")
        else:
            ChatWebSocket.ids[''+s+'']=self
            print(ChatWebSocket.ids)
    elif (data['st']=='st'):
        graph_db = neo4j.GraphDatabaseService()
        query = "START a=node:node_auto_index(uid='"+data['who']+"')  MATCH a-[:frd]-q RETURN q.uid as id"
        data1, metadata = cypher.execute(graph_db, query)
        print(data1)
        print(data)
        for y in data1:
            for j in y:
                if ''+str(j)+'' in ChatWebSocket.ids:
                    ChatWebSocket.ids[''+str(j)+''].write_message({"s":"st","id":data['id'],"con":data['con'],"time":data['time'],"on":data['on']})         
                else:
                    print("shit")
    elif(data['st']=='com'):
        graph_db = neo4j.GraphDatabaseService()
        query = "START a=node:node_auto_index(uid='"+data['who']+"')  MATCH a-[:frd]-q RETURN q.uid as id"
        data1, metadata = cypher.execute(graph_db, query)
        print(data1)
        print(data)
        for y in data1:
            for j in y:
                if ''+str(j)+'' in ChatWebSocket.ids:
                    ChatWebSocket.ids[''+str(j)+''].write_message({"con":data['con'],"id":data['id'],"s":"com"})         
                else:
                    print("shit")
    elif(data['st']=='cl'):
        print("cl")         
        if ''+s+'' in ChatWebSocket.ids: 
            del ChatWebSocket.ids[''+s+'']
            print(ChatWebSocket.ids)
            print("closed")                      
    elif(data['st']=='ty'): 

        s=str(data['whom'])

        if ChatWebSocket.ids[''+s+''].write_message({"g":str(data['who']),"s":"ty"}):
            print("ok")
    else: 
        doc={'who':data['who'],'whom':data['whom'],'mes':data['mes'],'id':data['who']+data['whom']}
        to.insert(doc)
        s=str(data['whom'])

        if ChatWebSocket.ids[''+s+''].write_message({"g":str(data['who']),"mes":data['mes'],"s":"m"}):
            print("ok")

    db=motor.MotorClient().open_sync().chat tornado_app = tornado.web.Application([(r'/websocket', ChatWebSocket),
    (r'.*', tornado.web.FallbackHandler), (r'/', MainHandler)],db=db)

   tornado_app.listen(5528)
   tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

here is what i am doing:when websocket opens clients sends his  uniqueid which python receives onmessage and create a dict with {uniqueid:websocketobject} when somebody  send the message it sends the unique id the python  get the websocket object as 
websocket object=dict{uniqueid} it then sends it to appropiate clients but sometimes it does not work and says none type attribute,even if  i  have saved the websocket object in that.

Comment: `None object has no attribute` means, you have somewhere value of None while expecting valid instance of some class. You shall debug your code to exact line, where it happens. Then your question shall turn either into understanding of the problem and solution, or to more focused question in style "why I get sometime None for call like ....". Another remark - edit your comments after code listing to be more readable - e.g. using numbered list when describing steps.

Comment: `Class ChatWebSocket(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):` The c of `class` should be in lower case. `class`, not `Class`. And indentation is not correct, this code cannot be run.